# how to set Content-Security-Policy for Stripe?

Tags: html, content-security-policy

I need to use Stripe in my application but I keep getting the error below in the browser console.

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).
```

I've tried to fix it by setting a rule in Content-Security-Policy but I cannot make it work.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
          content="script-src 'self' https://js.stripe.com />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>"
```

I run the code in localhost and I am using Firefox Developer Edition.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I am running the same problem and coldn't solve it yet. Can you please share with us, when you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

To allow a script resource at inline, your CSP needs to have 'unsafe-inline' set. But as you can understand from the name, this is unsafe and should be avoided if possible. Rather see if you can move the script code to a separate file.

Also, it seems like you are hitting a problem with a CSP and try to solve it by adding another one. Another CSP can only make it stricter, you can't allow something restricted by the original CSP. You should see if there is a CSP in a response header and modify that one instead.